# почему появляется столбец 'Unnamed'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

я создал датафрейм , в нём 3 колнки. Перегоняю его в файл. Читаю данные с файла и вижу новый столбец 'Unnamed' . Всё бы ничего , но я не могу его удалить , вылетает ошибка:

```
ValueError: labels ['Unnamed'] not contained in axis
```

откуда вообще он взялся и что с ним делать ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего вы сохранили CSV файл с индексом (по умполчанию).

Как это проверить:

```
In [31]: df.columns.tolist()
Out[31]: ['Unnamed: 0', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Пример:

```
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3), columns=list('abc'))

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

In [18]: df.to_csv(r'c:/temp/test.csv')
```

теперь если просто прочитать его, то получим столбец `Unnamed: 0` (т.к. индекс был безымянным):

```
In [20]: x = pd.read_csv(r'c:/temp/test.csv')

In [21]: x
Out[21]:
   Unnamed: 0  a  b  c
0           0  1  2  3
1           1  4  5  6
2           2  7  8  9
```

вот как это выглядит в CSV файле:

```
In [22]: print(Path(r'c:/temp/test.csv').read_text())
,a,b,c
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
2,7,8,9
```

Как это обойти:

```
In [23]: x = pd.read_csv(r'c:/temp/test.csv', index_col=0)

In [24]: x
Out[24]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

или сохранять DataFrame без индекса:

```
In [25]: df.to_csv(r'c:/temp/test.csv', index=False)

In [26]: print(Path(r'c:/temp/test.csv').read_text())
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9


In [27]: pd.read_csv(r'c:/temp/test.csv')
Out[27]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```